# Flash requirements for Deezer APIs

Tags: flash, deezer

do you know which Flash version is required (minimum) for using Deezer APIs (player)?

The documentation (http://developers.deezer.com/) doesn't say anything about Flash requirements but using a browser without flash I got "Flash is not installed or is too old" in console so maybe there is also a minimum version and I want to check it out to give a more friendly message.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash is required for the Deezer player (for stream encryption purposes), the minimum version to have is Flash Player 10.1.